# How to add multiple images in Google Documents?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs, images

Using basic *Insert->Image* menu option one can only add/select/upload images one by one. That can take lot of time especially if you want to add a lot.

[image]

In MS Word for example this option is present when you select several images on you local drive. Here in Google drive there is also an equivalent, but you can choose only one.

Since it's not by default, maybe there are some extensions that can add this functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@shershen, you can [select multiple images](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/select-multiple-files-folders#1TC=windows-7) in a Windows Explorer window and then drag them into the body of a Google Docs document (this worked with Chrome 34 and Windows 8.1). They will upload slowly, so give it a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

When you are selecting the images that you want to upload, hold down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key from start to finish and it will let you select more than one image.

As long as you are holding the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key the whole time, it will let you continue to select images.